# Python Socket Client wait time

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

How do I make a socket wait for only a certain time before moving on. I have a client that expects packet from a broadcast receiver in android but it waits forever whenever it doesnt get the packet over the socket. Is it possible to time out a particular receive request in python to maybe 5 secs? 
It maybe trivial but I am coming from a java background

```
 def obtain_packet(self):
        datarecevied = self.GetPCSocket().recv(4096)
        print datarecevied
        return str(datarecevied.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout):

> socket.settimeout(value)
>   Set a timeout on blocking socket operations. The value argument can be a nonnegative float expressing seconds, or None. If a float is given, subsequent socket operations will raise a timeout exception if the timeout period value has elapsed before the operation has completed. Setting a timeout of None disables timeouts on socket operations. s.settimeout(0.0) is equivalent to s.setblocking(0); s.settimeout(None) is equivalent to s.setblocking(1).